# Dim a LED with python without a loop

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pwm

I want to dim a LED with a Raspberry Pi 3. It works in loop perfect. But how do I dim the LED let's say 50% constantly? Without the script running in a loop. I want to start the python script that dims the LED and then stop it and the LED should still be dimmed. Is that even possible? The problem is, when I keep running the script the whole time, the CPU load of the Raspberry is very high (the whole time).

This is my code with the loop that works. I just want to remove Line 10, but then it doesn't work anymore. I'm a total python beginner.

```
import RPi.GPIO as IO
import time
IO.setwarnings(False)
IO.setmode (IO.BCM)
IO.setup(19,IO.OUT)
p = IO.PWM(19,100)
p.start(0)
while 1:
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you won't be able to get that behavior without continuously running a script. If you want to run your script in the background you should look into tmux. You can get it with

```
$sudo apt-get install tmux
```

And then run it with

```
$tmux
```

Then run your script. It will continue to run in the background as long as your RPi is turned on.

Edit: Formatting

Comment: This is what I did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a mix of python and hardware. Rather than use a loop (basically PWM) you can use a [variable resistance](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10613) as an [analog dimmer](https://learn.adafruit.com/all-about-leds/which-to-adjust).Then you can use the Rpi to increase the resistance digitally and get a dimmer light (not energy efficient and expensive depending on application). For fun here is a [really complex](http://www.powerelectronics.com/lighting/how-add-analog-dimming-virtually-any-led-driver) (atleast in my book)electronics heavy answer.